# Different no. of clusters for different data sets

Tags: loops, if-statement, for-loop, cluster-analysis

I am trying to plot results of multiple clustering algorithms on multiple data sets

The code is the following

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

from time import time

from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA 
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale


from sklearn import cluster, datasets, mixture
from sklearn.neighbors import kneighbors_graph
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

np.random.seed(0)


cs_arry=[[0,1,0,1],[1,0,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[1,1,0,1],[1,0,1,1],[0,1,1,1]]
cs_arry=np.array(cs_arry * 20)
colors = np.array([x for x in cs_arry])

#################
n_pts = 1500#####
#################


noisy_circles = datasets.make_circles(n_samples=n_pts, factor=.5, noise=.05)
no_structure = np.random.rand(n_pts, 2), None
my_circles=make_circ(n_samples=n_pts, factor=.35, noise=.025, in_fact=2)
##############################################
blob_centers = [(-10, -10), (-3, 10), (10, 10)] # adjust blob centers for blob data making 
##############################################
blobs=datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=n_pts, n_features=3, centers=blob_centers, cluster_std=3, 
                          center_box=(-20,20), shuffle=True, random_state=0)


clustering_names=['Input','K-means','K-medoids','AP','Spectral','Gaussian','Hierarchical']

nofclusters=3
plt.figure(figsize=(len(clustering_names) * 2 + 3, 9.5))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=.02, right=.98, bottom=.001, top=.96, wspace=0,
                    hspace=0)
data_sets = [noisy_circles, my_circles, blobs, no_structure]
plot_num = 1

for i_dataset, dataset in enumerate(data_sets):
    x, y = dataset
    x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)

    bandwidth = cluster.estimate_bandwidth(x, quantile=0.3)
    connectivity = kneighbors_graph(x, n_neighbors=10, include_self=False)
    connectivity = 0.5 * (connectivity + connectivity.T)

#clustering algorithms
    orig_data=cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=1)
    kmeans=cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=nofclusters,init='k-means++')
    Kmedoids=cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=nofclusters,init='random')
    heir = cluster.AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=nofclusters, linkage='ward',
                                           connectivity=connectivity)
    spectral = cluster.SpectralClustering(n_clusters=2,
                                          eigen_solver='arpack',
                                          affinity="nearest_neighbors")
    affinity_propagation = cluster.AffinityPropagation(damping=.9,
                                                       preference=-200)
    gmm=mixture.gmm(n_components=nofclusters, covariance_type='diag', random_state=None, 
                    thresh=None, tol=0.001, min_covar=0.001, n_iter=100, n_init=1, params='wmc', 
                    init_params='wmc', verbose=0)

    #####################################
    #####################################

    clustering_algo=[orig_data, kmeans, kmedoids, ap, spectral, gmm, heir]

    #####################################
    #####################################

    for name, algorithm in zip(clustering_names, clustering_algo):

        t0 = time.time()
        algorithm.fit(x)
        t1 = time.time()
        if hasattr(algorithm, 'labels_'):
            y_pred = algorithm.labels_.astype(np.int)
        else:
            y_pred = algorithm.predict(x)

        # plot
        plt.subplot(len(datasets), len(clustering_algo), plot_num)

        if i_dataset == 0:
            plt.title(name, size=18)
        if name=='Input':
            plt.scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1], color='k', s=10, marker='o', facecolors='none')
        else: plt.scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1], color=colors[y_pred], s=10, marker='o', facecolors='none')


        plt.xlim(-2, 2)
        plt.ylim(-2, 2)
        plt.xticks(())
        plt.yticks(())
        if name!='Input':
            plt.text(.99, .01, ('%.2fs' % (t1 - t0)).lstrip('0'),
                     transform=plt.gca().transAxes, size=15,
                     horizontalalignment='right')
        plot_num += 1

plt.show()
```

I was wondering if there is a way to set different numbers of clusters for different datasets. Specifically, I want the circle datas to have 2 clusters while the remaining sets have 3.

I tried inserting

```
if data_sets==noisy_circles or my_circles: 
     nofclusters=2
```

or

```
while data_sets==noisy_circles or my_circles: 
     nofclusters=2
```

before and after the for loop statement with no results.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary, so you can easily configure the number of clusters for each data set. You will also need to choose many other parameters, such as epsilon and minpts in DBSCAN.

You need to do it *inside* the for loop obviously, and make sure to set the value at every iteration. Otherwise, the next iteration may get the previous value, and you get incorrect results.